# Getting the sum of quantity by product id

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to get some results from my database. I have a table like this:

```
    ID ID_INVOICE PRODUCT QUANTITY PRODUCT_ID
    ------------------------------------------
     1    1          aaa     3       2
     2    1          bbb     2       3
     3    1          ccc     1       4
     4    2          bbb     3       3
     5    2          aaa     3       2
```

So after the query I would like to get something like

```
   aaa  6
   bbb  5
   ccc  1
```

The query is based on the `ID_INVOICE` so far I've tried this:

```
  SELECT product, sum(quantity) 
  FROM product 
  WHERE invoice_id = @p1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY product` clause, like so:

```
SELECT  product, sum(quantity) 
FROM product 
WHERE invoice_id = @p1
GROUP BY product;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0111/3)

Comment: @Sampath - You're welcome. You might also want to take a look at [**data.stackexchange.com**](http://data.stackexchange.com/). It is very cool as well, you can also query all the data of stackeexchange sites, users, posts, .. etc.

Comment: i get the error: In aggregates and grouping, The SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and ...

Comment: You're only getting this error because other columns might have been added into the select statement this must also be listed in the group by section.
Like 
    SELECT product_id, product, sum(quantity) 
    FROM product 
    WHERE invoice_id = @p1
    GROUP BY product,product_id;